Generic args in patterns require turbofish syntax - how to make it for Vec of tuples?
Let's say I have this code:
async fn get_product_data(product_id: Uuid) -> () {
    let product_with_skus: Vec<(product::Model, Vec<sku::Model>)> = Product::find_by_id(product_id)
        .find_with_related(Sku)
        .all(&*DB)
        .await
        .unwrap();

    match product_with_skus {
        Vec<(product::Model, Vec<sku::Model>)> => "prd".to_string(),
        _ => "trt".to_string(),
    };
}

product_with_skus is of type Vec<(product::Model, Vec<sku::Model>)>, also inferred correctly by the compiler itself. However, when I try to match it, it says Generic args in patterns require turbofish syntax.
I already tried:
Vec::<(product::Model, Vec::<sku::Model>)>, no luck.
How and where can I place turbofish? Please do not suggest changing that to two queries and using helper structs.

What are you trying to accomplish with this match? Even if it worked, you already know that product_with_skus is a Vec<(product::Model, Vec<sku::Model>)>. How could the _ match arm ever execute?

Matching is a versatile tool, but when starting out with Rust, it's most typically used to handle different enum variants. If your product_with_skus were an enum defined as enum Product { Variant1(Vec<...>), Variant2(HashMap<...>) }, it'd make sense to match it as match product_with_skus { Product::Variant1(vec) => { /* here you have a Vec<...> */ }, Product::Variant2(hash_map) => { /* here you have a HashMap<...> */ } }.

Maybe what you want is remove .unwrap(), change to product_with_skus: Result<Vec<(product::Model, Vec<sku::Model>)>> and replace the match with if product_with_skus.is_ok() { "prd" } else {  "trt" }.into() (might be Option and .is_some depending on what all returns)

I intended to use guards in those arms, but as I was stuck in the first one, I reached out for help. It can be refactored as @cafce25 writes, I know, I am just very curious on how to use the turbofish there.

You cannot match on type if that's what you're after

It would be great if you added an explanation of what you are trying to achieve precisely, because Vec<(product::Model, Vec<sku::Model>)> is a type, not a valid pattern; the compiler is confused too, and hints you at how to make that type look more like a pattern (because it's what the compiler expects to find there), but it's not really helpful in your case as that doesn't seem to be your intent.

The question is basically unanswerable at this point, as the goal of the match is unclear. If it's to use guards, use an identifier as pattern: match product_with_skus { x if x.bla() == "foo" => "foo", x if x.bla() == "bar" => "bar" }. But it's just guesswork because we don't know what you're after.

The problem with Vec::<(product::Model, Vec::<sku::Model>)> is that while it correctly employs a turbofish, it's not a complete pattern, for non-unit structs like Vec you need a struct body {..}:
async fn get_product_data(product_id: Uuid) -> () {
    let product_with_skus = Product::find_by_id(product_id)
        .find_with_related(Sku)
        .all(&*DB)
        .await
        .unwrap();

    match product_with_skus {
        Vec::<(product::Model, Vec::<sku::Model>)>{ .. } => "prd".to_string(),
    };
}

Notes:

This is an irrefutable pattern so any _ arm is superfluous and cannot be reached.
Since Vecs fields are private you can't match them outside of alloc::vec
While you can specify the type this way, it still has to be the same across all match arms.
Specifying the type on both let product_with_skus: Vec<(product::Model, Vec<sku::Model>)> and in the match is redundant, pick one and stick to it (personally I'd stick to specifing it in the let binding since I've never seen a type hint in a match).

